# The javascript of bootstrap v 4.3.1, is not working properly in firefox v 65.0.1, has anyone had this problem yet?

Tags: javascript, firefox, bootstrap-4

When accessing the bootstrap v 4.3.1 documentation in firefox v 65.0.1, I noticed that the javascript is not working properly, for example, the carousel component is not following its normal flow, which is to move to the next slide with the its transition animation, other components have the same problem. I noticed that in version 4.0.0 of bootstrap this problem does not occur. I recorded a video with the carousel example, follow the link:

https://youtu.be/ksT7KgZZXhY

I have a site with this version of bootstrap, which is not working because of this problem, and in other browsers it works normally and in the console does not present any problem, I do not know exactly if the problem is in firefox or javascript bootstrap, I tested in other machines with old versions of firefox and worked normally, but after updating firefox gave this problem again.

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to solve the problem. What happens is that in the performance settings of my computer the "Animate controls and elements in Windows" option was cleared, I do not know if this is a bug, as this is the first time I see a windows customization setting influencing loading of a website, anyway I left the link of the video with the solution.

https://youtu.be/9NhlpJpKpuQ